# jQuery when() doesn't seem to be working for each()

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the following code, it seems like the code inside of when() is still executing before the loop has finished. The log statement i have in the loop goes in after the one in the when statement. The code is not finishing the loop before executing what's in the when statement resulting in an empty array in my when.

```
function LocationsForState(state) {
  console.log(state);
  $.ajax({
     url: '/Home/GetApartmentsForStateJSON?state=' + state
  })

  .done(function (apartments) {

     //set up markers 
     var markers = [];

     var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
     $.each(apartments, function (index, apartment) {
        var address = apartment.Address;

        geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
           if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
              var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
              var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();

              markers.push({ "latitude": latitude, "longitude": longitude, "icon": "../../Content/img/mapMarker.png", "baloon_text": 'This is <strong>Texas</strong>' });
              console.log('In loop' + markers);
           }
        });
     });

     $.when(markers).then(function () {

        console.log('In when' + markers);

        var myMarkers = { "markers": [markers] };

        //set up map options
        locationMap.mapmarker({
           zoom: 6,
           center: 'United States/' + state,
           markers: myMarkers
        });

     });
  });
}
```

Comment: If geocoder.geocode is an asynchronous call, when you get to $.when your `markers` is still an empty array, so I think it isn't a deferred object like $.when is expecting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case this should work,

```
function LocationsForState(state) {
    console.log(state);
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Home/GetApartmentsForStateJSON?state=' + state
    }).done(function (apartments) {
        //set up markers 
        var markers = [];
        var defs = [];

        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        $.each(apartments, function (index, apartment) {
            var address = apartment.Address;
            var deferred = $.Deferred();
            defs.push(deferred.promise());
            geocoder.geocode({
                'address': address
            }, function (results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                    var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();                    
                    markers.push({
                        "latitude": latitude,
                        "longitude": longitude,
                        "icon": "../../Content/img/mapMarker.png",
                        "baloon_text": 'This is <strong>Texas</strong>'
                    });
                    console.log('In loop' + markers);
                    deferred.resolve();
                }
            });
        });

        $.when.apply($, defs).then(function () {
            console.log('In when' + markers);
            var myMarkers = {
                "markers": [markers]
            };

            //set up map options
            locationMap.mapmarker({
                zoom: 6,
                center: 'United States/' + state,
                markers: myMarkers
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`$.when` works on deferred objects such as object returned by `$.ajax` call and not on an `Array` of `Objects`

You don't seem to have fully understand what `$.when` does.

[**KNOW MORE ABOUT IT!**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/)

Comment: Well. What is the proper way to make sure my code executes in the correct order in this scenario?

Comment: As an aside, you could create a new `$.Deferred` object to call `.when` on that is `.resolve`d when all the `geocoder.geocode` callbacks have completed.

Comment: Actually *when* will work for the objects which are not promises or deferreds, but which will be treated as resolved and done callback will be fired immediately.

Answer (score 0):

`$.when` expects deferred objects.

You should do something like:

```
$.each(apartments, function (index, apartment) {
    var address = apartment.Address;

    // create the deferred object
    var deferred = $.Deferred();

    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
       if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
          var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
          var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();

          // resolve the deferred when request is complete
          deferred.resolve({
              "latitude": latitude,
              "longitude": longitude,
              "icon": "../../Content/img/mapMarker.png",
              "baloon_text": 'This is <strong>Texas</strong>'
          });
          console.log('In loop' + markers);
       }
    });

    // add promise to markers
    markers.push(deferred.promise());
 });
```

Then, you can do:

```
$.when.apply($, markers).then(...)
```